# How do I compose the UriTemplate for a WCF function to set a property?

Tags: c#, wcf

I would like to be able to set a property on an object via my CRUD interface by using a URL such as:

http://example.com/service/object?property=value

To that end I tried the following, which is invalid.

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "device/{deviceID}?{propName}={propValue}")]
    [OperationContract]
    void SetDeviceProperty(string DeviceID, string propName, string propValue);

    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "device/{deviceID}?{propName}")]
    [OperationContract]
    string GetDeviceProperty(string DeviceID, string propName);
```

The closest example I could find was something like

```
propertyName={proeprtyName},propertyValue={propertyValue}
```

...but that would make for some ugly URLs.  I'd like to keep it as simple as the object path followed by ?name=value

Answer (score 0):

For the POST part it looks like it's unnecessary to create such UriTemplate you can just do it like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "sendTransaction")]
    SomeResponse RequestMethod(SomeRequest req);
```

Where SomeResponse is a class for Response and SomeRequest is the request.

For the GET part I don't think you can make it more elegant, your choice would be to make it all POST. Hope this helps.